# My first permutation lesson - what is this code missing?

Tags: javascript

Translated (apparently wrongly) from a C++ book.
If I can get it to work, then I can start trying to understand it.

```
function recPermute(soFar, rest)
{
    if (rest==="")
    {
        console.log(soFar);    
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0; i<rest.length; i++) // <<< error was in not declaring the "i"
        {
            var next = soFar + rest[i];
            var remaining = rest.substr(0,i) + rest.substr(i+1);
            recPermute(next, remaining);
        }
    }
}   


function listPerm(s)
{
    recPermute("",s);
}

listPerm("kitcap")
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Is there an error, or is it not doing what you think it's doing?

Comment: Yeah...when you post questions here, you can't just post code and be like HAVE FUN FINDING THE PROBLEM!M!MM! You actually have to say what the problem is. If you don't know, you need to try and describe what's happening as best you can.

Comment: Could be wrong since I don't really know C++, but it looks like in your JavaScript code you're recursively calling your recPermute function, but in your C++ code you're not.

Comment: no permutations are being printed out...

Comment: Yeah, that's not specific enough.

Comment: You seem to have an eternal loop as callmehiphop pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [declare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) `i` so it's scoped to `recPermute`:

```
for(var i=0; i<rest.length; i++)
```

Without the `var`, [it'll be created as a global](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488) so each call to `recPermute` will alter it for any other calls.

Answer (score 1):

for JavaScript, use [charAt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp), instead of using array like acessing.

```
var next = soFar + rest.charAt(i);
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two?

Comment: @JosephSilber `.charAt()` has been part of the language longer. Array-like access is [new with ES5](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.5.2). So, can't be used in older browsers, if they need to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could be an issue is you are using effectively the same `i` for each call to the function. You need to declare a local `i` or it will be declared in the global scope.

```
for(var i = 0; ....
```